# Custom close reason for "push questions"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

It's always been difficult for me to decide how to treat questions based on clearly incorrect reasoning such as [this one](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15939/why-do-climate-experts-from-the-un-ipcc-never-mention-milankovitch-cycles).

A lot of times someone is pushing pseudoscience or a well-discredited conjecture.

It's probably not a good idea to reflexively suppress contrarian views, but sometimes a line is crossed and the question doesn't pass the "smell test". Extraordinary claims requiring extraordinary data and all that.

[History Stack Exchange](http://history.stackexchange.com) has a specific close reason for this:

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to **promote or discredit** a particular theory, cause, group, idea, or person. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about history as defined in the help center.

(This is how they deal with Holocaust deniers and the like).

There is [this Earth Science meta discussion](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/should-we-add-a-not-mainstream-science-close-reason) about a closely related type of question.

I noticed that when the rock-identification close reason was put in, a bunch of previous ones went away, even the "not about Earth Science" one that had to be put back in later. If this SE is only allowed a limited number of close reasons, that would make me reconsider this idea because the ones we have all seem necessary.

---

**Edit, May 5**

I feel this idea merits more discussion than a single comment. I see more and more push questions.

A question like [this one](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16872/how-much-those-new-buildings-contributed-to-flooding-in-the-area) seems like a push question to me; maybe someone wants to sue the builders.

Comment: I think we only need a custom close reason if we get many of a particular type.  I haven't noticed we get many crackpot theories, do we?

Comment: @gerrit We regularly get climate change denial questions and plenty of  flat and hollow earth stuff.

Comment: I like the reason given in comments for this question: [Where can I find evidence that the earth is flat?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/where-can-i-find-evidence-that-the-earth-is-flat), which was closed. The reason being "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not asking a serious question in good faith".

Comment: @Fred That's pretty much what the History SE close reason says.